# Does removing elements from an array create new hidden classes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm reading about V8 hidden classes in order to write more efficient OOP code, but I'm confused about arrays of objects.

I learned I should use the same sets of properties in my Objects and add the properties in the same order. Since Arrays are also Objects, pushing into an array should be OK, but what about removing the last element of an Array (`delete array[array.length-1]`)? Will it create a useless hidden class as it also deletes a key? Am I better off setting the last element to null or something, or simply reducing the `.length` property by one?

P.S. I'm asking for Node.js, if that matters.

Comment: Why not `.pop()`?

Comment: Sure, `pop` too. Will it have an impact on performance?

Comment: `.pop` certainly not: it is a basic and recommended way to remove elements from an array. JavaScript engines are optimised to deal efficiently with that. With `delete` it is a different story.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know.

Comment: What about `array=[]`?

Answer (score 1):

@trincot's answer is wrong. The .pop() function changes the hidden class of the array which deoptimizes the v8 engine and this does in fact negatively impact  performance. I would not recommend .pop() if your end-goal is monomorphism with hidden classes. This blog recommends .slice()

https://www.sitepoint.com/immutable-array-methods-javascript/

Also, this guy Thorsten Lorenz has put out tons of excellent resources for learning about this. Definitely check check out his Github.
https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-perf
https://github.com/thlorenz/deoptigate